# Set location of one object using another object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 Express, I can't seem to find a way to set the location of an object based on the object of another. I tried using this:

```
OvalShape1.Location.X = P1.Location.X + 50
```

P1 is a rectangle. If I can get any help with this that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
OvalShape1.Location=New Point(x,y) 'where x=copy the x property value as well in y value
```

**OR**

```
OvalShape1.Top=P1.Top
OvalShape1.Left=P1.Left
```